# VS 2022 Windows - Build Error - Release: Error Loading info.plist ... Could not find file ....<name.appp\info.plist

Tags: info.plist

Trying to build a 'release' version after debugging sucessfully on Windows and a Mac.

Build error is: rror loading 'bin\Release\net7.0-ios\ios-arm64\WOApp.app\Info.plist': Could not find file 'C:\dbs_dev\WOApp12_3.01\WOMauiApp1\bin\Release\net7.0-ios\ios-arm64\WOApp.app\Info.plist'.
WOMauiApp1  C:\dbs_dev\WOApp12_3.01\WOMauiApp1\bin\Release\net7.0-ios\ios-arm64\WOApp.app\Info.plist

I searched the web for suggestions, as well as all of StackOverflow. Nothing close to this issue.

I have an info.plist file.

I removed the Platforms\ios\info.plist - same results.
I've added it back - same results.
I've cleaned the solution - same results.
I've deleted the Obj and Bin folders - rebuild - same results.

Update: I created a new project - Hello World - and compiled the release - Remote Device - no errors.  Specifically IOS: C:\dbs_dev\vb.net.Development\xamarin\samples\MauiApp1\bin\Release\net7.0-ios\ios-arm64\MauiApp1.app

There is/was no info.plist file in this 'hello world' directory.

I compared the Info.plist between the two solutions and they were/are the same.

I copied the 'Hello world' info.plist to the non-working solution and built under release-Remote Device - same error - can't load the file.